# Python display excel values plot

Tags: python, excel, plot

I am using this code->

```
import xlrd 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

loc = ("file path") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    x = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
    y = sheet.cell_value(i, 1)
    print(x, y) 
    plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(rotation=50, horizontalalignment='right', weight='bold', size='large')
plt.xlabel('Date', weight='bold', size='large')
plt.ylabel('Total Bad Ports', weight='bold', size='large')
plt.show()
```

To read the data from a two column .xls file and display a plot using its data.
I have a graph containing two errors.
1. The y axis does not display the values.
2. I have an empty plot when trying to display a line graph.
The graph is successfully (without the y axis values) using plot.bar or plt.plot(x, y, 'ro').

*The form of data is

```
2020 01 28 1900 875
2020 01 29 0700 844
2020 01 29 1300 580
2020 01 29 1900 587
2020 01 30 0700 589
2020 01 30 1300 582
```

(column1->2020 01 30 1900, 2020 01 29 0700 etc and column 2->875, 844 etc)

Thanks in advance:)

[image]

Comment: post few lines of data from you file

Comment: 2020 01 28 1900 875
2020 01 29 0700 844
2020 01 29 1300 580
2020 01 29 1900 587
2020 01 30 0700 589
2020 01 30 1300 582

Comment: The 1st column contains the data + time value and the 2nd the count value.

Comment: add this into question, that each row of data will by in separated line

Answer (score 0):

The silly 1. problem was solved..there was an empty starting row in the .xls file apparently not allowing the y axis values to be properly displayed.

I still can't have a line diagram using the plt.plot command although I have a good enough plt.bar graph. Any tips are appreciated:)